# Wie verwendet man Bindestriche bei mehrteiligen Eigennamen richtig?

Tags: style

Ich stolpere oft über die Bildung von zusammengesetzten Wörtern mit Hilfe von Bindestrichen, v. a. wenn diese Eigennamen enthalten. Ich bin oft versucht die Wörter durch einfaches Hintereinandersetzen, ähnlich dem Englischen, zu bilden. Aber darf man das? Was wäre in den folgenden Beispielen richtig:

> Alcatel-Lucent-Lecture

oder

> Alcatel Lucent Lecture

oder etwa

> Alcatel Lucent-Lecture

*Alcatel Lucent* ist ein Unternehmen und der Name schreibt sich nun mal getrennt. Wie ist es mit

> Wiener-Kintchine-Theorem

oder dem

> state-of-the-art-Produkt

Gibt es hier auch andere, erlaubte Formen der Zusammensetzung?

*Ergänzung und Korrektur der Tags sind willkommen.*

Comment: Wie ist das 1. Beispiel zu verstehen - ist *Lecture* hier ein Anglizismus (yuck!) oder wird ein englischsprachiger Text zitiert?

Comment: Es ist ein Anglizismus. Man könnte nun argumentieren, dass dann auch 'Alcatel Lucent Lectures' ein Eigenname ist und die Bindestriche entfallen können. Was bedeutet yuck?

Comment: (yuck = expression of slight distaste in light of what I think is a terribly unnecessary anglicism :)

Comment: Ist yuck ein Anglizismus? ;)

Comment: nicht wirklich - das war etwas großzügig zwischen Englisch und Deutsch gewechselt :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Die [amtliche Rechtschreibung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/regelwerk.html) regelt solche Fälle in §50:

> Man setzt einen **Bindestrich zwischen allen Bestandteilen** mehrteiliger Zusammensetzungen, deren erste Bestandteile aus Eigennamen bestehen.
>
> Beispiele:
>
> Albrecht-Dürer-Allee, Heinrich-Heine-Platz, Kaiser-Karl-Ring, Ernst-Ludwig-Kirchner-Straße, Rainer-Maria-Rilke-Promenade, Thomas-Müntzer-Gasse
>   Elbe-Havel-Kanal, Oder-Neiße-Grenze, La-Plata-Mündung
>   Albert-Einstein-Gedenkstätte, Georg-Büchner-Preis, Jacob-und-Wilhelm-Grimm-Preis, Goethe-Schiller-Archiv, Johann-Sebastian-Bach-Gymnasium, Van-Gogh-Ausstellung am Lago-di-Como-seitigen Abhang, Fidel-Castro-freundlich

Namenszusätze wie *von*, *van*, *de*, *da* usw. schreibt man

- innerhalb einer Zusammensetzung klein:
  *Leonardo-da-Vinci-Gymnasium, John-von-Neumann-Straße*
- am Anfang eines zusammengesetzten Nomens groß:
  *eine Da-Vinci-Ausstellung, ein Van-Gogh-Gemälde*
- am Anfang eines zusammengesetzten Adjektivs klein:
  *da-Vinci-artig, de-Gaulle-treu*

Comment: Viele Texter und PR-Leute mögen es natürlich nicht, wenn ihre sorgfältig konstruierten, globalisierten und optimierten Firmen- und Markennamen von blöden Sprachregeln durchkreuzt werden, und versuchen deshalb, die Schreibweise *mit* Leerzeichen durchzusetzen. Ich bin sicher, daß das als ["Deppenleerzeichen"](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deppenleerzeichen) bekannte Phänomen zu einem nicht unbedeutenden Teil davon herrührt.

Comment: @Pekka Meinst du das Deppen Leer Zeichen?

Comment: Rosa von Praunheim ist nicht mit Rosa Luxemburg verwandt oder verschwägert - ersteren ziert ein 'von', letztere, ganz klassenbewusst, keins.

Comment: @user_unkown mein Fehler. Danke für den Hinweis! Ich habe das Beispiel in "John-von-Neumann-Straße" geändert, auch wenn er ursprünglich *János Neumann Margitta* hieß.

Answer (score -2):

In Abwandlung von splattnes Empfehlung, die im Zweifelsfall die richtige ist, beliebe ich manchmal, die weniger enge Bindung durch setzen von Leerzeichen zu verdeutlichen, also:

```
 Heinrich-Heine-Platz wird zu 
 Heinrich-Heine - Platz
 Albert-Einstein-Gedenkstätte zu 
 Albert-Einstein - Gedenkstätte
```

richtig ist das wahrscheinlich nicht, und Profis, die nicht einfach ASCII-Zeichen benutzen, sondern Textsatz mit LaTeX und Co. verwenden womöglich 3/4 oder ½-Leerstellen, 4/5-Bindestriche die eine Spur dicker oder dünne sind, und noch subtilere Möglichkeiten, die mit einer 105-Tastatur den Schreibfluss aber enorm behinderten, wollte man sie einüben.

Da es aber eine gewisse Freiheit in der Schreibung gibt, und der Duden, mit seiner Politik der Erfassung gängiger Schreibweisen pragmatische Regelverstöße geradezu ermuntert, wollte ich diesen Ansatz ganz unverbindlich vorstellen.