# Rechtschreibung zusammengesetzter Wörter unterschiedlicher Sprachen

Tags: spelling, compound

Wie sollten, nach neuer Rechtschreibung, zusammengesetzte Wörte aus englischen und deutschen Begriffen geschrieben werden?

Zum Beispiel:

- „Standby-Betrieb“, „Standbybetrieb“
- „Empfangs-Thread“, „Empfangsthread“

Comment: Teilweise verwandte Frage hierzu: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/794/wie-verwendet-man-bindestriche-bei-mehrteiligen-eigennamen-richtig

Comment: Als weiteren Bastard möchte ich "Backshop" in die Debatte werfen. Da kann man kein Rückwärts oder Undo kaufen, sondern Brötchen, Semmeln, Wecken und Schrippen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Generell werden Komposita im Deutschen bekannterweise zusammengeschrieben, wobei es die Faustregel gibt, dass man ab vier Komponenten (oder um eine bestimmte Betonung oder Bedeutung zu erreichen oder einen Schwerpunkt zu setzen) Bindestriche setzt. Sofern der englische Begriff einigermaßen sicher in der deutschen Sprache angekommen ist, gelten dafür dieselben Regeln.

Ich würde im Zweifel den Bindestrich setzen, wenn nicht klar ist, wie bekannt das englische Wort ist (obwohl man sich dann auch fragen kann, warum es das englische Wort sein muss). Im Einzelfall kommt es daher darauf an, "wie deutsch" das Wort mittlerweile ist.

Beispielsweise erlaubt die Rechtschreibung "Standbybetrieb", der Duden empfiehlt jedoch "Stand-by-Betrieb" (man beachte den Bindestrich zwischen den beiden Wortkomponenten im englischen Wort). Den Server hingegen findet man auch gerne ohne Bindestrich (im Duden gefunden: Servernetzwerk und serverbasiert. Komposita mit Service (Serviceangebot, Servicegebühr usw.) werden ebenfalls ohne Bindestrich geschrieben. Die langfristige Tendenz ist klar, ein Wort, das in der deutschen Sprache häufiger verwendet wird, wird auch wie ein Wort der deutschen Sprache behandelt (und auch gebeugt).

"Empfangsthread" und "Sendethread" habe ich übrigens auch schon gesehen. Hier schadet in meinen Augen aber auch der Bindestrich nicht: "Empfangs-Thread" und "Sende-Thread".

---

Mittlerweile habe ich auch auf der Duden-Website eine Aussage dazu gefunden:

> Im Grunde gelten bei der Frage Getrennt- oder Zusammenschreibung von Wörtern aus dem Englischen die gleichen Regeln wie bei deutschen Zusammensetzungen. Verbindungen aus zwei Substantiven werden zusammengeschrieben, also beispielsweise Economyclass, Poleposition, Shoppingcenter, Braintrust, Bottleparty. Alternativ dazu kann auch ein Bindestrich gesetzt werden, beide Substantive müssen dann natürlich großgeschrieben werden: Economy-Class, Pole-Position. Die Bindestrichvariante bietet sich vor allem dann an, wenn solche Verbindungen in der Zusammenschreibung schwer lesbar sind, wie etwa bei dem Wort Desktoppublishing, hier ist die Schreibung Desktop-Publishing zu empfehlen.
>
> Ist der erste Bestandteil ein Adjektiv, kann zusammengeschrieben werden, wenn die Hauptbetonung auf dem ersten Teil liegt, daneben ist auch die Getrenntschreibung möglich: Blackbox oder Black Box, Hotspot oder Hot Spot. Wir empfehlen hier jeweils die Zusammenschreibung.
>   Ansonsten gilt in Anlehnung an die Herkunftssprache nur die Getrenntschreibung: High Fidelity, Electronic Banking, Top Ten.
>   Bei Verbindungen aus Verb und Partikel sind Zusammen- und Bindestrichschreibung möglich: Hangover, Blackout, Countdown, Handout neben Hang-over, Black-out etc. Hier empfehlen wir auch die Zusammenschreibung.
>
> Bei Aneinanderreihungen und Zusammensetzungen mit Wortgruppen muss grundsätzlich mit Bindestrich durchgekoppelt werden: Current-Account-Bereich, Public-Relations-Abteilung, Do-it-yourself-Programm, Multiple-Choice-Aufgabe.

Comment: +1 sehr gute und vollständige Antwort. Das hilft wirklich weiter.

Comment: Die alte Regel, dass man bei unübersichtlichen Zusammensetzungen ab vier Komponenten 
einen Bindestrich setzt, gibt es nicht mehr. Bei der neuen Rechtschreibung darf ein Bindestrich auch in unübersichtlichen Komposita aus weniger als vier Gliedern gesetzt werden.

Comment: Die Faustregel gilt immer noch, denn sie hat nie verboten, bei weniger als vier Gliedern Bindestriche zu verwenden. Das hat mit der neuen oder alten Rechtschreibung nichts zu tun. IMO hat sich nur die Regel geändert, wie Komposita mit einzelnen Ziffern oder Buchstaben geschrieben werden, und Empfehlungen, in ungünstigen Kombinationen eher den Bindestrich zu setzen (Druck-Erzeugnis/Drucker-Zeugnis). Zitat Belles Lettres: "Der Binde­strich dient allein dem Ziel anzuzeigen, daß die In­kor­pora­tion aus unüberwindlichem Grund nicht stattgefunden hat oder nicht ordentlich geschrieben werden kann."