# Zusammengesetzes Wort: Bindestrich oder nicht?

Tags: spelling, compound, hyphen

Wie ist die korrekte Schreibweise für zusammengesetzte Wörter. Werden diese mit einem Bindestrich getrennt oder nicht? Mir geht es vor allem um Leichtathletik-Verein / Leichtathletikverein oder Leichtathletik-Zentrum / Leichtathletikzentrum.

Bei Wikipedia finde ich beide Schreibweisen gemixt. Auch auf Korrekturen.de (http://www.korrekturen.de/regelwerk/schreibung_mit_bindestrich.shtml) oder Duden.de habe ich nichts Gescheites gefunden.

Auch habe ich gelesen, dass Wörter zur besseren Lesbarkeit in beiden Varianten richtig geschrieben sind. Es hieß, dass "Telefon-Flatrate" beispielsweise besser zu lesen sei als "Telefonflatrate".

Comment: Die Antwort zu [Rechtschreibung zusammengesetzter Wörter unterschiedlicher Sprachen](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1669/1224) gilt auch hier.

Comment: Siehe auch [Schreibung mit Bindestrich:
 Hervorhebung und Verdeutlichung](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Bindestrich/Hervorhebung.html?MenuId=SpellingRules030)

Answer (score 10):

Grundsätzlich werden zusammengesetzte Wörter (Komposita), die keine Eigennamen
als Bestandteile enthalten, ohne Bindestrich zusammengeschrieben.

Allerdings *kann* gemäß § 45 des amtlichen Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung in einigen Fällen ein Bindestrich gesetzt werden:

#### 1. Hervorhebung einzelner Bestandteile

Zur Hervorhebung einzelner Bestandteile des Kompositums *kann* ein Bindestrich gesetzt werden.

> die Ist-Stärke
>
> die Soll-Stärke

(In einigen Ausnahmefällen ist die Schreibung mit Bindestrich fest geworden.)

#### 2. Unübersichtliche Komposita

Ein Bindestrich *kann* gesetzt werden, wo sich bei sinngemäßer Auflösung eines unübersichtlichen Kompositums die Hauptfuge ergibt.

> Arbeiter-Unfallversicherungsgesetz
>
> Gemeindegrundsteuer-Veranlagung
>
> Straßenverkehrs-Zulassungsordnung

(Bei der alten Rechtschreibung wurde ein Bindestrich nur in unübersichtlichen Zusammensetzungen aus mehr als drei Wortgliedern gesetzt. Bei der neuen Rechtschreibung darf diese Regel auch bei Komposita aus weniger als vier Gliedern angewendet werden.)

#### 3. Vermeidung von Missverständnissen

Ein Bindestrich *kann* entsprechend der Bedeutung des Kompositums zwischen Zweit- und Erstglied gesetzt werden, um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden.

> Druckerzeugnis
>   Druck-Erzeugnis
>   Drucker-Zeugnis

#### 4. Zusammentreffen von drei gleichen Buchstaben

Beim Zusammentreffen von drei gleichen Buchstaben in substantivischen Komposita *kann* ein Bindestrich gesetzt werden.

> Kaffeeersatz
>   Kaffee-Ersatz
>
> Schifffahrt
>   Schiff-Fahrt

(Bei zusammengesetzten Adjektiven und Partizipien schreibt man üblicherweise ohne Bindestrich.)

Answer (score 6):

**Beides ist erlaubt.**

Es gibt keine festen Regel für das Einfügen von Bindestrichen. Insgesamt soll eine Variante gewählt werden, die dem Leser ein möglichst rasches Erfassen des Wortes ermöglicht.

Das hängt auch von der verwendeten Schriftart ab. In mannshohen Buchstaben auf der Fassade einer Sporthalle wirkt das anders als auf dem Kopf des Briefpapiers eines Sportvereins und wieder anders im Fließtext eines Zeitungsartikels über dieses Zentrum.

Ich sehe das so:

> *Leichtathletikzentrum* ist in Ordnung
>   *Leichtathletik-Zentrum* ist in auch Ordnung
>   *Leicht-Athletik-Zentrum* das geht zu weit
>   *Leicht-Athletikzentrum* das stiftet Verwirrung

Wollte man die *Leicht-Athletik* von der *Schwer-Athletik* trennen, und beide Ausprägungen in einem Aufsatz miteinander vergleichen, wäre vermutlich auch die Schreibweise *Leicht-Athletik-Zentrum* akzeptabel. In diesem Kontext wäre sogar die Schreibweise *Leicht-Athletikzentrum* denkbar.

In den meisten Fällen ist davon aber abzuraten, weil *Leichtathletik* noch eine überschaubare Länge hat und von einer Vielzahl von Lesern nicht mehr als Kompositum wahrgenommen wird.

---

*Ergänzende Betrachtung*

1829 wurde die berühmte "Erste **Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaft**" gegründet, die aber schon 17 Jahre nach der Gründung, also 1846, in "Erste K. K. priv. **Donau-Dampfschifffahrts-Gesellschaft**" umbenannt wurde. Es wurden also schon damals zwei Bindestriche eingefügt. Bindestriche in langen zusammengesetzten Wörtern sind also keine neue Modeerscheinung und gab es auch schon lange vor der Rechtschreibreform.
(Seit 1995 heißt das Unternehmen übrigens "DDSG Blue Danube GmbH")

Comment: Es begann so schön, und dann kommt dieses Leicht-Athletikzentrum daher. Da muss jeder Leser vermuten, dass sich das "Leicht" auf das Zentrum, also vielleicht eine Halle bezieht, schlanke Aluträger mit Stoff bespannt, wahrscheinlich.

Comment: @userunknown: Genau das war für mich der Grund, dahinter die Worte "das stiftet Verwirrung" zu setzen.

Comment: Wurde damals wirklich die "Erste Donaudampfschifffahrtsgesellschaft" gegründet, oder nicht doch eher die "Erste Donaudampfschiffahrtsgesellschaft"? Ich meine, von der letzten Rechtschreibreform konnten sie ja damals noch nichts wissen. :-)

Comment: @celtschk: Wortwörtlich von hier: http://www.ddsg-blue-danube.at/de/ueber_uns_geschichte.php Du darfst nicht vergessen, dass die Reform von 1996 ja schon die dritte Reform seit Gründung der DDSG war. 1876 und 1901 gab es auch schon Rechtschreibreformen. Tatsächlich war "Schifffahrt" bis zur Reform 1901 richtig, ab dann waren "Schifffahrt" und "Schiffahrt" gleichermaßer erlaubt. Erst 1905, also in der "Reform der Reform" wurde nachträglich die Regel eingeführt, dass der dritte Konsonant weggelassen werden soll wenn ihm ein Vokal folgt. 1996 wurde wieder der Zustand von vor 1901 hergestellt.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ah, danke für die Aufklärung. Dank der Umbenennung 1995 ist sie ja jetzt unabhängig von allen deutschen Rechtschreibreformen :-)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Die "Verwirrung" bekrittel ich nicht, das "akzeptabel" findet meine Abneigung. Geschrieben werden soll ja so, dass es verstanden wird.

Comment: Ich persönlich würde über "Leicht-Athletik" stolpern, ähnlich wie über "Straßen-Bahn" oder "Flug-Hafen". Kann es sein, dass bestimmte zusammengesetzte Begriffe irgendwann als eigenständige Begriffe wahrgenommen werden, sodass man weniger trennt?

Answer (score 5):

Der Bindestrich ist meistens optional.

Bei bekannten Begriffen wirkt der Bindestrich überflüssig oder verwirrt den Leser:

> Ausflugs-Ziel, Welt-Atlas, Unternehmens-Berater, Hunde-Leine

Sind die Begriffe aber (für den Leser) neu oder selten, so hilft der Bindestrich dem Leser, das Wort schon beim ersten Lesen sinnvoll zu zerlegen.

> Recycling-Quote, Messer-Schleifer, Hinterhof-Werkstatt, Automatik-Getriebe, Auslass-Ventil

Im weiteren Textfluss kann auf den Bindestrich verzichtet werden.

Ferner sind Bindestriche nützlich, um bei wörtlicher Rede eine bestimmte Betonung zu verdeutlichen:

> Blumento-Pferde (scherzhafte Aussprache von Blumentopferde)
>   Ü-ber-deut-lich (überbetonte Silbentrennung bei der Aussprache)

Comment: Ich würde bei der "Pferderasse" eher "Blumento-Pferde" schreiben. So sieht es eher nach einer unvollständigen Silbentrennen aus (unvollständig, weil die Pferde nicht getrennt wurden).

Comment: Ich würde in einem Text nicht zwischen den beiden Formen wechseln. Entw. von Anfang an sich für die Binde-Striche entscheiden oder ganz und gar auslassen. Auch würde ich - wenn man mehrere Begriffe einführt - alle Begriffe gleich behandeln. Also nicht sowas wie "Blumentopferde essen Sommera-Stern"

Comment: Danke, celtschk, du hast vollkommen recht. Ich habe es korrigiert.
@Em1: Diese Freiheit hast du grundsätzlich, es sind ja beide Formen richtig. Im journalistischen Bereich wird manchmal gefordert, neue zusammengesetzte Begriff erst zu trennen, dann zusammenzuschreiben.

Comment: Den Satz "Im weiteren Textfluß kann auf den Bindestrich verzichtet werden." würde ich streichen. Innerhalb eines Textes sollten alle Wörter immer gleich geschrieben werden. Man wechselt innerhalb eines Textes nicht "du" und "Du" ab, man wechselt nicht "Delphin" und "Delfin" ab, und auch nicht "Leichtathletikzentrum" und "Leichtathletik-Zentrum". Du kannst einmal eine Wahl treffen, musst dann aber dabei bleiben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Im Prinzip stimme ich dir zu, aber viele Lektorate verfahren beim Bindestrich anders (Gründe habe ich genannt). Auch deshalb steht da "kann", schön ist es allerdings nicht.

Comment: "Recycling-Quote, Messer-Schleifer, Hinterhof-Werkstatt, Automatik-Getriebe, Auslass-Ventil" gehören allesamt zusammengeschrieben. Vor Jahren, als Recyclingquote noch neu war, mag man es wegen der unterschiedlichen Herkunft (Englisch/Latein?) getrennt haben. Im gleichen Text beides zu nutzen scheint mir auch eine Schnapsidee.

Comment: Rohrohrzucker finde ich toll, oft in Zutantenlisten zu finden. Dort wäre der Bindestrich meines Erachtens angebracht. Zur Erleichterung des Lesens, denn sicher niemand erwartet Zucker aus röhrenförmigen Ohren o. ä.

Answer (score 3):

Grundsätzlich ist beides möglich. Man kann Komposita zusammenschreiben oder durchstoppen (mit Bindestrich). Manchmal ist es auch angebracht, der Verständlichkeit halber, beide Varianten in einem Wort zu mischen:

> Telephonhörer-Anschlusskabel

Die Auswahl einer Variante bleibt dem Sprachgefühl überlassen. Als Faustregel kann man Wörter, die als Zusammensetzung gewöhnlich sind oder nicht allzu lang sind, grundsätzlich zusammenschreiben; bei überlangen oder ungebräuchlichen Wortzusammensetzung ist es angebracht, diese durchzustoppen.

Comment: Ich wöllte mich über das *ph* äußern, aber dann fiel mir auf, dass das Konzept des Telephonhörer-Anschlusskabels insgesamt aus der Zeit stammt, als das ph noch die Alleinherrschaft im Telefon hatte ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: [Das stimmt nicht.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Telephon%2CTelefon&year_start=1800&year_end=2015&corpus=20)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Und warum kriege ich jetzt eine Downvote?

Comment: @FUZxxl: Das darfst Du mich nicht fragen (sprich: Ich war’s nicht). Ich kann nur raten, dass es an mangelnder Begründung liegt, bzw. daran, dass die Situation in den Rechtschreibregeln tatsächlich nicht so einfach ist.

Answer (score 2):

Wie die Anderen schon gesagt haben: beides ist erlaubt.

Meines Wissens ist die Variante ohne Bindestrich allerdings empfohlen. So hat es mir mein Deutschlehrer zumindest damals in der Schule erklärt. (Die genaue Begründung habe ich leider vergessen.)

Ich vermeide deshalb Bindestriche bei zusammengesetzten Worten, wenn möglich. Nur bei technischen Begriffen, gerade wenn sie aus dem englischen Raum kommen, benutze ich Bindestriche häufig.

Hier ein [Beitrag aus der Zwiebelfisch-Kolumne](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebel-fisch-das-elend-mit-dem-binde-strich-a-274613.html) im Spiegel:

> Der Bindestrich (Divis), nicht zu verwechseln mit dem (längeren)
>   Gedankenstrich, erfüllt die Funktion einer Lesehilfe. Bei
>   Zusammensetzungen mit Fremdwörtern gilt: Der Bindestrich dient zur
>   Hervorhebung des Unbekannten, Unerwarteten, Ungewöhnlichen. Für viele
>   deutschsprachige Menschen sind Wörter wie Computer, Internet und
>   online heute nichts Ungewöhnliches mehr, sodass sie in
>   Zusammensetzungen wie Computerbranche, Internetfirma und Onlinedienste
>   auf den Bindestrich verzichten. Dies entspricht durchaus dem Prinzip
>   der deutschen Sprache: Wortzusammensetzungen, die sich bewährt haben,
>   werden als ein Wort geschrieben. Zusammensetzungen mit
>   Fachfremdwörtern, die noch keinen festen Platz im deutschen Wortschatz
>   haben, dürfen/sollten gekoppelt werden: Remote-Rechner, Viren-Patch,
>   Consulting-Unternehmen.

(Aber Achtung, der Autor, Bastian Sick, ist kein Sprachwissenschaftler, sondern Journalist. ;))