# Bindestrich zur besseren Lesbarkeit

Tags: usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zusammengesetzes Wort: Bindestrich oder nicht?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/zusammengesetzes-wort-bindestrich-oder-nicht)

Ich möchte das Wort webtechnologielastig lesbarer Gestalten. Dazu habe ich die Alternativen

- Webtechnologie-lastig
- Web-technologielastig
- Web-Technologie-lastig

Das erste Beispiel würde mir am besten Gefallen, da es den Fokus auf lastig setzt, was in meinem Kontext zum Verständnis beiträgt. Sind alle Alternativen gülitig oder gibt es noch einen anderen Grund warum eine der anderen vorzuziehen wäre?

Comment: Vielleicht lohnt es sich ganz umzuformulieren, um das Wort in Teile zu zerhacken. Oder besteht ein größeres Umformulierungsverhinderungsbedürfnis?

Comment: Es besteht tatsächlich ein UVB. Der Satz ist zur Zeit schön prägnant, könnte aber vemutlich umstrukturiert werden. Das würde aber vermutlich nicht meine Neugier nach Beantwortung der gestellten Frage stillen.

Comment: Webtechnologielastig ist doch ok für ein Kunstwort, dessen Bedeutung man vielleicht sowieso besser in einer Wortgruppe fasst. Bindestriche und zweifelhafte Großschreibung sind da nur optische Bremshügel und helfen gar nicht.

Comment: Das Wort wird besonders amüsant, wenn es zusammengeschrieben wird, da man Komposita mit englischsprachigen Bestandteilen normalerweise mit Bindestrichen trennt und hier also auch die Technologie des Webens gemeint sein könnte... Natürlich nur, wenn man den Kontext nicht kennt :)

Comment: Bei allem Umformulierungsverhinderungsbedürfniserwägungsgebot: 'Technologie' klingt für mich immer so ein bisschen überzogen, wenn es nicht schwerpunktmäßig um Hardware/technische Anlagen geht. Bei einem hauptsächlichen Programmierungsbezug ist 'Technik' vielleicht angemessener, weil dieses Wort außer für Geräte auch schon lange für abstrakte Konzepte und Methodik etabliert ist.

Comment: @TehMacDawg: Webtechnik klingt ja noch mehr nach Weben als nach dem Web. In der Regel meint man mit Webtechnologien in der Tat einzelne Technologien, also Komponenten, Bibliotheken, Standards, z.B. HTML5, WebGL, jQuery usw. - da passt aus meiner Sicht der Begriff Technik nicht. Eher gibt es eine Programmiertechnik wie z.B. Extreme Programming. Auch wenn ich "webtechnologielastig" für ein schreckliches Wort halte, ist es doch dichter an dem dran, was hier gemeint ist, weil die Begriffe etabliert sind. Diese Software-Technologien zu entwickeln ist ebenso Ingenieurskunst wie Hardware-Entwicklung.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Ja, eigentlich meinte ich 'Techniken'... Dein Argument leuchtet mir aber ein.

Comment: @OregonGhost: Und ich habe extreme Programming bislang für eine Managementtechnik gehalten und verstehe unter Technologie auch die großen, historischen Linien: Manufaktur, Handwerk und Muskelkraft, Industrie und Dampfmaschine, Elektronik und Automation. Die Technologie der Maya. Wäpptechniken also für mich, oder auch Webtechniken.

Comment: Wenn ich mir die [Google-Fight-Ergebnisse](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=Webtechniken&word2=Webtechnologien) anschaue, wage ich zu behaupten, dass *Webtechnologien* wesentlich gebräuchlicher dafür ist als *Webtechniken*. Bei den "historischen Linien" würde ich eher von technologischen Errungenschaften als von Technologien sprechen. Handwerk oder Muskelkraft als Technologie zu bezeichnen ist mir noch nicht untergekommen.

Comment: Hi, vielen Dank für die guten Tipps, aber der Comments-Thread entwickelt sich langsam zu einer Diskussion, die vielleicht eher in einem Chat stattfinden sollte?

Comment: @OregonGhost Jetzt, da du dies anmerkst: Die Ursprungsfrage stellt eigentlich gar nicht klar, ob es um das Web oder das Weben geht. Was man nicht alles in ein Wort hineinliest, ohne es zu merken. Es ist ein wenig wie bei dem Vexierbild mit der alten Dame und dem jungen Mädchen: Bei *Webtechnologien* lese ich automatisch ein kurzes *e*, bei *Webtechniken* ein langes ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zusammenschreibung zweier Bestandteie eines Kompositums drückt eine stärkere Bindung aus als Verbindung mit Bindestrich.

Wenn man -- wie in der Frage -- ein Kompositum aus drei Bestandteilen baut, eine der beiden "Schnittstellen" zusammenschreibt und die andere mit Bindestrich verbindet, dann kann sich die Bedeutung verschieben, wenn man Zusammenschreibung und Bindestrich vertauscht. Vergleiche:

> Ziegenleder-Hose
>
> Ziegen-Lederhose

Im Bezug auf das Kompositum in der Frage heißt das folgendes:

> Webtechnologie-lastig

bedeutet, etwas macht starken Gebrauch von Webtechnologie. Web und Technologie sind stärker verbunden als Technologie und -lastig.

> Web-technologielastig

bedeutet, etwas ist technologielastig im Bezug aufs Web. Auf eine Web-Art und -Weise technologielastig. Hmmm.

> Web-Technologie-lastig

Hier sind, wie in "webtechnologielastig", beide Bindungen gleich stark. Das wirkt sich nicht auf die Bedeutung aus, ist aber dadurch vielleicht unschön, dass zwei Bindestriche drin sind.

---

Das bestätigt den Schluss, dass die erste Version die sinnvollste ist.

Comment: Es fehlt der Vergleich mit der ursprünglichen Form: webtechnologielastig (da die Technologie- vs. Technikfrage off topic ist).

Comment: @userunknown: That is plainly wrong. Read until the end, please.