# Kubakrise oder Kuba-Krise

Tags: noun

Gibt es für die Konstruktion von Wörtern wie:
Kubakrise / Kuba-Krise
Krimkrise / Krim-Krise
bestimmte Regelungen? Sind beide Fälle verwendbar? Falls ja, welcher von beiden wäre stylistisch angebrachter?

Comment: Related: [Zusammengesetzes Wort: Bindestrich oder nicht?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5222/9551)

Comment: Guter Verweis - In dem Beitrag wird explizit nur der Fall ohne Eigennamen behandelt. Wie wird es also in einem Fall mit Eigennamen gehandhabt? Während der zugehörige Wikipedia Artikel kein Bindestrich verwendet ist in der Presse oftmals die Variante mit dem Bindestrich zu finden.

Comment: Eigennamen werden in diesem Fall nicht anders behandelt als alle anderen Nomen.