# Wie schreibt man "in-situ-Verfahren"? Groß, klein, getrennt?

Tags: spelling, capitalization, loanword, compound, hyphen

Ich möchte gerne wissen, welche Rechtschreibung nach welcher Regel korrekt ist.

- a) in-situ-Verfahren
- b) In-Situ-Verfahren
- c) In-situ-Verfahren
- d) in situ Verfahren
- e) weitere Vorschläge

Comment: Vergleich man Online-Referenzen (u. a. [Tu Dresden](http://tu-dresden.de/die_tu_dresden/fakultaeten/fakultaet_forst_geo_und_hydrowissenschaften/fachrichtung_wasserwesen/iaa/service/skripte/ws_10_11/Modul_Erk_San_Teil_San_Vortrag_Dr_Schlenker_08.12.2010.pdf), [Helmhotlz-Zentrum Geesthacht](http://www.hzg.de/institute/coastal_research/structure/operational_systems/KOI/index.html.de)) erhalte ich mind. 4 verschiedene Möglichkeiten. Einigkeit herrscht wo anders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [in situ](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/in_situ)

Die stehende adjektivische lateinische Wendung *"in situ"* wird in wissenschaftlichen Texten zur Umschreibung einer natürlichen Lage genommen. Deshalb darf man diese Wendung auch nicht mit Bindestrichen zusammenfügen. Folgende Schreibweisen sind also grammtikalisch korrekt:

> in situ Verfahren
> in situ Hybridisierung
> der (archäologische) Fund wurde in situ belassen

Sobald man aber ein näher bestimmtes Verfahren als **Substantiv** verwenden möchte, muss man hilfsweise eines Bindestrichs setzen:

- [Rechtschreibung zusammengesetzter Wörter unterschiedlicher Sprachen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/rechtschreibung-zusammengesetzter-worter-unterschiedlicher-sprachen)

Daraus relultiert folgende korrekte Schreibweise:

> In-situ-Hybridisierung
> Fluoresenz-in-situ-Hybridisierung
> In-situ-Sanierung

Die richtige Schreibweise hängt also von der grammatikalischen Verwendung im Text ab.

Comment: Für Deine Behauptung, dass „in situ Verfahren“ und „in situ Hybridisierung“ korrekt wären, würden mich Quellen interessieren; insbesondere, da Du zu den anderen Antwortenden, die Links angegeben haben, und IMHO auch zu §43 der [Regeln des Rates für deutsche Rechtschreibung](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf) im Widerspruch stehst.

Comment: Vielleicht führt  ein Klick auf den oben an erster Stelle stehenden und in [**fett gesetzten Duden-Link**](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/in_situ) zur Klärung? Kommentarlose Downvotes helfen hier jedenfalls niemand.

Answer (score 7):

Laut [Duden, Rechtschreibregel 68](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/Gro%C3%9F-%20und%20Kleinschreibung#D68), ist Variante c) korrekt.

Answer (score 4):

Richtig ist: In-situ-Verfahren.

[Ref](https://www.korrekturen.de/forum.pl/md/read/id/30658/sbj/in-situ-verfahren/) mit weiterführendem [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/GrossKlein/pgf55-56.html)