# How to include an English word in a German sentence?

Tags: grammar, declension

I am currently writing my master thesis in computer science. The thesis is written in German, but due to the subject a lot of words are English. The thesis is about the deployment of an application (which means the distribution and installation of the software). I have a lot of sentences like this:

```
Sie können lokal getestet werden bevor sie auf einen Cloud Anbieter deployt werden.
```

If have two question about this sentence:

- How do I write combinations of English and German nouns? E.g. `Cloud Anbieter` or `Cloud-Anbieter` or `Cloudanbieter`? I think it is obvious that I cannot translate the term `Cloud` in this context, so I need to include it somehow in my German text.
- How to decline English verbs in a German sentence? E.g. would `to deploy something` be `deployt werden` or `deployed werden`?

Comment: Concerning the second part of your question, this post might help: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/wie-ist-die-richtige-schreibweise-geliket-geliked.

Comment: Thanks! The question/answer is really good. So I would go with `deployt`.

Comment: Both questions have already been answered on this site. @c.p. already provided the link to [question 2](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4435/1224); and here's [question 1](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1669/1224)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Germanizing" English loanwords has no generally accepted rules. See

- [Wie ist die richtige Schreibweise – "geliket"? "geliked"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4435/wie-ist-die-richtige-schreibweise-geliket-geliked)

Both, *deployment* and *to deploy* are well known technical terms which are not easy to transfer to German grammar rules. Both *deployt*, and *deployed* are awkward in a German sentence.

Therefore I would use the German counterpart *[Softwareverteilung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softwareverteilung)* and *verteilen*. You may also define somwehere in your introduction how you use these, e.g.:

> Unter Softwareverteilung (engl. *deployment*) versteht man...

English terms in compounds are usually built using a hyphen: *Cloud-Anbieter*.

Comment: As a software developer in Germany have to disagree with "deployt" and "deployed" being awkward in a German sentence, as they're used interchangably all the time. For example "...auch das Portal/Webseite wurde jetzt deployt..." is something one sees often.

Comment: @Jimmerz28 That may well have changed in the last 4 years. The Germanized verb *deployen* may eventually find its way into the dictionaries. But still, a rule whether to say *deployt* or *deployed* may take some time.

Answer (score 4):

I would like you to reconsider writing your thesis in german. While I feel more comfortable writing in german, too - it gets very difficult with such problems at hand.
Also, if you are reading a lot of english texts for your thesis, you will begin to think in english - then you want to write down your result and have to translate your sentence to german.
Also, translating a lot of concepts is very difficult - translations are never catching the exact meaning.
Last, you would have the added benefit of demonstrating good english skills and a wider target audience for your thesis.

Comment: You are somehow right. I really thought about writing in English. But everybody involved in the thesis (my professor, second corrector, my colleagues, myself) are native German speakers. I wrote some chapters and ended up with a bunch of simple grammatical question, nobody could answer me. Like can you says that something is `shifted to the cloud` or is it `ported to the cloud`? Or both? Of course, everybody will understand what I mean, but is it correct? Neither my professor nor I could tell that for sure. Now I have 90 solid pages in good German and a bunch of blog posts in English.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig Somehow, writing the thesis in English and use [english.SE] or [ell.SE] makes more sense to me than writing it in German and then as here how to best use English fragments. ;)

Answer (score 3):

1. `Cloud-Anbieter`is the right form to use. Don't use `Cloudanbieter`, switching the language 'mid-word' makes reading difficult. As Elena pointed out in comments, don't use a "Deppenleerzeichen" (space) instead of a hyphen.
2. I am not sure about that, but there should be fitting translations for verbs. E.g. `deploy` could be translated to `installieren`. If you can't find any good translation there is topic on [canoo](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2007/10/05/wie-konjugiert-man-verben-aus-dem-englischen/), that might help.

Comment: It is really hard to find a good translation. `To deploy sth.` is not the same as `installieren` or `verteilen`. It is a kind of fixed technical term.

Comment: DO NOT write "Cloud Anbieter". German compounds are written either in one word or with a hyphen, but NEVER EVER with a Deppenleerzeichen. That would be a spelling mistake.

Comment: @elena I wasn't aware there was a rule, thank you

Comment: Deppenbindestrich instead of "Deppenleerzeichen"? Huh. I'd rather go with Cloud Provider.

Comment: @Raphael me as well, but as I said, I didn't know the rule. ->[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leerzeichen_in_Komposita)

Comment: How would you write terms with more then one English word like `Shared Nothing Prinzip`? Also `Shared-Nothing-Prinzip`?

Comment: @ThomasUhrig yes, `Shared-Nothing-Prinzip`. If you search it on Google, you will actually find it used like that on Wikipedia.

Comment: Nein, `deployen` ist definitiv kein feststehender technischer Begriff. Da es kein deutsches Wort ist, können auch keine Rechtschreibregeln darauf angewendet werden. Eine mögliche Übersetzung ist `aufbringen`.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, I'd use

> Cloudprovider or Cloud-Provider

which is closer to the English original (if capitalised) but still understandable; "Provider" is widely used for (German) internet and mobile service providers.

Comment: @Takkat "Cloud Provider" as English compound certainly needs no hypen (in most circumstances); are you suggesting to Germanify the grammar but not the words?

Comment: You may be interested in the [official rule §45 E1](http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Bindestrich/pgf40-45.html) which says so - alternatively we can build a composite *Cloudprovider* (but this hurts my eyes too much).

Comment: @Takkat In that case, I'd take the proper compound without "Deppenbindestrich"; but apparently, that's a matter of taste.