# How to nominalize verbs that have an adverb?

Tags: adverb, spelling, compound, nominalization

Maybe the question is misleading (I am a German native speaker myself), let me give you an example. I want to nominalize the verb *stellen* in the following sentence:

> Wir haben etwas online gestellt. (*We put something online.*)

But, since the word *online* describes where or how something was put *(gestellt),* how would the nominalization look like? I could think of

> Nach dem online Stellen
>   Nach dem Onlinestellen
>   Nach dem Online-Stellen

whereas the second option looks false to me.

Comment: Onlinestellen – See http://www.canoo.net/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Bindestrich/Hervorhebung.html?MenuId=SpellingRules030 # http://german.stackexchange.com/q/1669/1224 # http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5222/1224 # http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20581/1224 # and probably a couple of further related (or even duplicated?) questions

Comment: You can ask questions in German here, by the way.

Comment: Wenn deine Muttersprache Deutsch ist, und du in einem Forum, das sich mit Deutscher Sprache beschäftigt, eine Frage über einen Aspekt der Deutschen Sprache stellst, warum tust du das in einer Fremdsprache, noch dazu wenn du dabei befürchtest missverstanden zu werden?

Comment: Damit andere Leute, die Deutsch vielleicht lernen möchten eher auf die Frage treffen und Hilfe finden und nicht so wie ich eine bestehende Frage, wie jene, die als Dublikat existiert, aufgrund der dämlichen Fragestellung jedoch nicht finden kann. Es ist immer noch eine englischsprachige Platform